Azure SQL backup policy
I have Azure SQL Elastic pool which manage my databases.
I'd like to have some automation which always set my custom backup retention policies, like weekly retention is 30days, for all newely created databases.
I tried to research elastic pool, but couldn't find anything what would be helpful there, then I research SQL Server and it looks like this can only be done per database, which in may case in not an option.
The most promissing solution I found was to add a custom policy and apply it to the resource group.
I tried a few version of this, but it didn't work. The validation and deployment always succedded, but the retention policies hasn't been updated, even after I refreshed the policy state:
az policy state trigger-scan --resource-group "MY_RG"

The policy I have currently looks something like this:
 {
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies",
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/9b7fa17d-e63e-47b0-bb0a-15c516ac86ec"
        ],
        "deployment": {
          "properties": {
            "mode": "incremental",
            "template": {
              "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "parameters": {
                "serverName": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "resources": [
                {
                  "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'),'/default')]",
                  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicies",
                  "apiVersion": "2023-08-01-preview",
                  "properties": {
                    "monthlyRetention": "PT0S",
                    "weeklyRetention": "P30D",
                    "weekOfYear": 0,
                    "yearlyRetention": "PT0S"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "parameters": {
              "serverName": {
                "value": "[field('fullName')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Is there anything I'm missing? Or do you know any other way I can approach this?
